# PyTorch Values Bairley Changing

Tags: python, machine-learning, curve-fitting, mathematical-optimization

I have a simple model in pytorch based on the [quickstart](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/quickstart_tutorial.html) except instead of a pre-made data-set I am trying to find parameters for a mathematical function to fit a curve, I am then trying to feed back into the network the "goodness of fit" for the curve. My output is (6 parameters) for the function.

I give as input:

- The independent input at N inputs (lets call it *x*)
- The dependent output at N outputs (lets call it *y(x)*)
- The output of the mathematical function *f* for each point of *x*, and parameters *p* (lets call it *f(x, *p*)* where *p* is the same for all *x*)
- The last set of guessed parameters *p*

Now I have a simple cross entropy loss function, and stochastic gradient descent for back-propagation in a simple feed forward network, for which the output is a new set of 6 parameters for *f*, *p'*, I take *p'* and *x* and put it into *f* and back-propagate based on *y(x)* and *f(x, p')*, ***not p***, loss is indirectly based on the output.

Behavior I am observing is that the output does not change very much, really just the lower digits (also should it be outside the bounds [-1, 1]), neither has the loss. I have made attempts to divide it out by the absolute value of the absolute maximum value of the output when feeding it back into the network but no luck

Questions: A: Am I doing anything fundamentally wrong? B: Could this be a normalization problem? C: How might I diagnose this problem?

Thanks!